# ajax load content is using variables from Previously loaded file

Tags: php, html, ajax, load

I have 3 PHP files as A,B,C.

The A file contain some public variables like:

```
$page_title = 'abcdefg';
......
```

The B file make some magic on variables from A file, and will return html like:

```
<div><?php echo $page_title ?></div> // $page_title is came from A file
```

C file is the index page:

```
<?php include('a.php'); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content_container"></div>
    <button id="load">Load</button>
</body>
</html>
```

ajax code is

```
function get_content(){
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'b.php',
        success: function(data){$('.content_container').html(data);}
    });
}
```

If I use the get_content() function inside $(document).ready() the code well work fine and show me the $page_title value when I load the page.

But if I use the get_content() function inside $('#load').click() no result will return, and this is my target :(.

Note: I can include the A file inside the B file, But in this case I will load it twice, inside B and C Files, so am looking for another way.

Any help !

Best wishes.

Comment: How do you get $page_title value in B file?

Comment: when I include A file inside C, the B file will read $page_title

Comment: try 'b.php?v=2', give version to renew the cache of the browser.